# Display specific ads on my hybrid app

Tags: admob, hybrid-mobile-app, ads

trying to learn to develop a hybrid app. I want to learn how to implement specific ads on the application using adMob.

As I've found out, adMob only promotes other people's apps. Is there a way to promote a specific ad (kinda like promoting/sponsoring), like a product or company?

Comment: Everything google allows you todo, is written down somewhere by them. The developer.google.com or the admob site will be more useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use a plugin like https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova.

Then in your admob account just setup a banner with no mediation and publish the ads you want with your own internal campaigns. There is no cost on this.